# Django bootstrap files not found

Tags: python, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I have set up Django with bootstrap following some tutorials but even when I am doing the same as in the tutorials Django doesn't find the static files.

My Project has the following structure:

```
webshop
    shop
        migrations
        templates
        ...
    static
        css
            bootstrap.min.css
        ...
    webshop
        ...
    db.sqlite3
    manage.py
```

In the data settings.py I have added

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

And in the Index.html I load the static files with following code:

```
<head>
        <title>Webshop</title>
        {% load staticfiles %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" type="text/css"/>
</head>
```

But Django can't find the data bootstrap.min.css.

Comment: Can you replace `{% load staticfiles %}` with `{% load static %}`? Also checkout [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/) on how to load static files.

Comment: Replaced it, but is still not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your HTML code add

```
{% load static %}
```

and your setting.py add

```
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

Answer (score 2):

As per Django documentation you should specify the folder when the static file is not tied to a specific app:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    '/var/www/static/',
]
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

In your case it could be:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static'/
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    '/path/to/webshop/static',
]
```

Also please pay attention in the @kiran.koduru comment above regarding `{% load static %}`. This is the right way to load static files in Django templates.